# Different Color Bars at top and bottom of Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress page at http://saint57records.com/blog/ has different colors at the top and bottom of the page. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css file (http://saint57records.com/style/all.css - line 3), you have set **background-color** of **html** element is **#eeeeee**. But are you using a custom background color for **body** (**#e6e6e6**), right? That's the reason you see 2 line at top and bottom with different color.
So I think you should use the same color for 2 elements which I mentioned above or just remove  **background-color:#eeeeee;** in your css file http://saint57records.com/style/all.css (line 3). That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following:

```
html {
background-color: #eeeeee
}
```